# direct Python output to text file and html

Tags: python, html, text

I'm trying to write a code and to have the output in console, text file and html file, but the problem with html file that all the output appear in one like not like as appeared on the console line by line:

```
def main():

import re, sys
from StringIO import StringIO
from os.path import basename,join

f2 = open('helloworld.html','w')
f1 = open("testing.txt",'w')

f= raw_input("\n Hello, use.\n \n PLease type in the name of the  press 'Enter': ") 

capture = StringIO()
save_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = capture


print f
x = "John"
g = "Peter"


if re.search(x,f) :
    print "It contains  John"
if re.search(g,f):
    print "It contains Peter"
if re.search(x,f) and re.search(g,f):
    print "It contains both persons"

sys.stdout = save_stdout    
print capture.getvalue()
template = """
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>%(text)s</p>
    </body>
</html>
"""

html_message = template %{"text":capture.getvalue()}


f2.write(html_message)
f2.close()

f1.write(capture.getvalue())
f1.close()
```

can anyone help me with this ? is this an appropriate way to have a copy of the output into text file and html file ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the newline character with `<br>` for the html file

Something like this would work:

```
count=capture.getvalue().count('\n')-1 #you should do a count so that you don't add a newline at the end
html_message = template %{"text":capture.getvalue().replace('\n', "<br>\n", count)}
```

Instead, you could use this which will format the output html file nicely:

```
template = """
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>%(text)s
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
"""

count=capture.getvalue().count('\n')-1
html_message = template %{"text":capture.getvalue().replace('\n', "<br>\n           ", count)[::-1].replace('\n', "", 1)[::-1]}
```

Comment: what should I do above ?

Comment: Replace your line 'html_message = template %{"text":capture.getvalue()}', with what I gave you and it should work

Comment: I have one more question regarding to html output above ?
i did a code in python output to be symmetric two columns between them a space. but in html the two columns adjacent

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, open a new question and post your code and an example of what you want

Comment: sorry for bothering you but I just open a new question if you could help me with it ?

Comment: Please this is the link :=== http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219591/python-output-to-html-and-text-file ===